# Error after updating angular 7 to angular 10 - AspNetBoilerplate

Tags: angular, aspnetboilerplate

I've downloaded aspnetboilerplate angular template and upgraded the dependencies in my project according to it.
After resolving compile time errors, I got a runtime error showing in the console window of the browser (screenshot attached)

```
ERROR TypeError: abp.ajax is not a function
    at Function.push.Kc6q.AppPreBootstrap.getApplicationConfig (AppPreBootstrap.ts:44)
    at Function.push.Kc6q.AppPreBootstrap.run (AppPreBootstrap.ts:34)
    at root.module.ts:35
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:913)
    at Array.<anonymous> (root.module.ts:30)
    at ApplicationInitStatus.runInitializers (core.js:26795)
    at core.js:28060
    at _callAndReportToErrorHandler (core.js:28161)
    at core.js:28058
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:386)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I forgot to add the following line in angular.json

```
    "scripts":[
    ...
    "./node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.jquery.min.js"
    ]
```